# Creating PDF in Laravel 5.2 using html2pdf

Tags: php, laravel-5, html2pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF in Laravel 5 using spipu pdf but have not succeeded. How do I go about it?

That is my code segment:

```
public function download_pdf()
{       
  try {
  ob_start();
  include  'resources\views\retailer_dashboard\procurement\invoice.blade.php';
  $content = ob_get_clean();

  $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
  $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
  $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
  $html2pdf->Output('/download_pdf.pdf');
}
catch (Html2PdfException $e) 
{
    $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
    echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post any errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Please return a error in the question...

Comment: HTML2PDF_exception in parsingHtml.class.php line 118:
ERREUR n°4 : Code HTML non valide, les balises ne sont pas fermées dans le bon ordre.Etat : Array
(
[0] => page
[1] => div
[2] => div
[3] => div
[4] => div
[5] => a
)
HTML : ....png" width="120" height="40"></span> </a>
<button type="button"...

Answer (score 0):

Do `echo view('path.to.view'));`, print the view, do not include it.

Then your code:

```
ob_start();
echo view('resources.views.retailer_dashboard.procurement.invoice');
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

If you include the `blade.php` file you are including with the Blade directives instead of the compiled php code generated.

You can also do this:

```
$content = view('resources.views.retailer_dashboard.procurement.invoice');
```